# Drawing a line on Bing Maps through 180 deg long

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Drawing a line through 180 degrees longitude on the Bing Maps control doesn't work as I expect. 180 degrees longitude runs from north to south through the Pacific Ocean, so if I wanted to draw a line from (10, 175) to (-10, -175) - expecting a small (10 degrees) line crossing the equator somewhat north of New Zealand - I get a line stretching all the way around the globe, crossing the equator at 0 degrees long (south of Greenwich). How can I draw a line that transverses 180 deg long?

Comment: The endpoints have different latitudes, which would mean the line crosses the equator. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, the line crossing the equator is irrelevant. I'm expecting a small line crossing the equator for ten degrees long north of NZ but Bing Maps is drawing the line around 350 degrees long. I'll clarify this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to *approximate* this by drawing two lines, from point **a** almost on the 180 degree meridian then from just past the 180 degree meridian to point **b**. So in a method that returns an `IEnumerable<MapPolyLine>`, where `a` is the closest point with a negative longitude and `b` is the closest point with a positive longitude:

```
var aa = Math.Abs(b.Longitude - a.Longitude - 360);
var bb = Math.Abs(b.Latitude - a.Latitude);

var aaa = 180 + a.Longitude;
var bbb = (bb / aa) * aaa;

var line1 = new MapPolyline
{
    Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0),
    Width = 5
};
line1.Locations.Add(a);
line1.Locations.Add(new Location(a.Latitude - bbb, -179.999));
yield return line1;

var line2 = new MapPolyline
{
    Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255),
    Width = 5
};
line2.Locations.Add(new Location(b.Latitude + bb - bbb, 179.999));
line2.Locations.Add(b);
yield return line2;
```

This could be cleaned up further and is just a workaround. Also some artifacts can appear but this seems pretty reliable.